# JUNIT test case for void method

Tags: junit

I have a method whose JUnit test case I have to write. It just calls the main processing method of the project and does nothing else. Also, the main processing method also has return type as void.

How shall I test such a "method1"?

```
public void method1() {
     obj1.mainProcessingMethod():
}
```

Comment: What does the method do? What is the outcome/result of the method? Does it write a file? Does it change the database?

Comment: it just calls another method. Nothing else

Comment: Well, is must do _something_

Answer (score 2):

Given a class:

```
public class A {
    private Obj obj1;

    public void method1() {
        obj1.mainProcessingMethod();
    }

    public void setObj1(Obj obj1) {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
    }
}
```

In test for this class, the only thing to test would be verification whether method `obj1.mainProcessingMethod()` was invoked exactly once.

You can achieve this with Mockito.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class ATest {
    private Obj obj1 = Mockito.mock(Obj.class);
    private A a = new A();

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        a.setObj1(obj1);
        a.method1();
        Mockito.verify(obj1).mainProcessingMethod();
    }
}
```

Here you create a mock object for class `Obj`, inject it into instance of `A`, and later use mock object to check which method invocations it recorded.

Comment: also it is good approach to inject mocked object: `@Mock Obj obj1; @InjectMock A a`

Comment: @SergiiGetman, good point, but we have to mention also, that test class should be annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the test you need to verify that the method mainProcessingMethod(): is called on the object obj1.

you can use something like

```
Mockito.verify(yourMockObject);
```